# How do some libraries override operator[] with multiple return types?

Tags: c++, templates

I have come across various container libraries in modern day C++ that have found a way to override the `operator[]` and still return multiple types. For example, using [nlohmann::json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), the following code is all valid:

```
const nlohmann::json settings;

// set some values:
j["pi"] = 3.141;
j["happy"] = true;

// get some values:
std::string deviceName = settings["device"];
bool yesOrNo = settings["blah"];
```

How is this possible, especially in the case cases? In my own attempts, I've run into the common error case of "could not deduce template argument for 'T'". I do think it has to do with some proxy object (likely `value_t` or `object_t`), however I haven't been able to follow the template logic back deep enough in the case of nlohmann's json implementation (which is pretty impressive!).

Comment: See [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant).

Comment: They don't.   The `operator[]()` of `j` will return a reference to an object.   That object will have overloads of `operator=()` that accept arguments of different types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of `nlohmann::json::operator[]`, it returns a `reference`, which is defined as a `value_type&`, where `value_type` is defined as `basic_json`.   The `basic_json` class has a templated conversion operator that can convert a json value to any type that the `basic_json::get()` method supports, which includes booleans, integers, strings, etc.  So, what you are essentially doing is this:

```
//std::string deviceName = settings["device"];
std::string deviceName = settings["device"].operator std::string();
//which is effectively
//std::string deviceName = settings["device"].get<std::string>();

//bool yesOrNo = settings["blah"];
bool yesOrNo = settings["blah"].operator bool();
// which is effectively
//bool yesOrNo = settings["blah"].get<bool>();
```